# How to store parsed .csv file into an array?

Tags: arrays, c, csv

I've read the .csv-file and then I have to store contents into an array. If someone could show me the way, that would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    FILE* fpointer = fopen("beispiel.csv", "r");

    if(fpointer == NULL){
        perror("It is unable to open");
        return -1;
    }

    char line[100];

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fpointer) != NULL){
        char *abc;

        abc = strtok(line, ",");

        int i = 0;
        char arr[100];

        while(abc != NULL){
            //printf("%s",abc);
            abc = strtok(NULL, ",");
            abc = arr[i];
            i++;
            printf("%d", arr[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the issue you are having?

Comment: Did you mean save word which separated by comma character and save each word to array arr ?

Comment: The consecutive lines `abc = strtok(NULL, ",");` and `abc = arr[i];` are misguided at best — the second undoes any good that the first did.  You should also be getting compiler warnings for assigning a `char` to a pointer.  The `printf()` following is also probably not what you want, especially as you've already incremented `i`.  You need to look long and hard at the inner loop and rewrite it.